# Getting a missing keyword error in CASE WHEN statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm getting a missing keyword error in Oracle SQL and I'm not sure why. Here's my code. I want to have a column split by different times depending on the variable P1_DATE_CHOOSER. (I'm using Apex App Developer if that helps).

```
Select START_DATE, 
Round(Avg(Run_TIME), 3) as "Average_RunTime", 
Round(Max(Run_TIME), 3) as "Max_RunTime", Round(Median(Run_time), 3) as "Median_RunTime" 
from 
  (Select job_id,
      Case P1_DATE_CHOOSER 
          WHEN 'Daily' THEN TRUNC(start_time) as 'START_DATE'
          WHEN 'Weekly' THEN to_char(start_time, 'WW') as 'START_DATE'
          WHEN 'Monthly' THEN to_char(start_time, 'MONTH') as 'START_DATE'
       END,  
      1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) as "RUN_TIME"
   from NI_INFA_ACTIVITY_LOG_V
   order by job_id asc, start_time asc)
group by START_DATE order by START_DATE
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: At the first look... move `AS START_DATE` after `END` word of `CASE ... END` statement.

Comment: First, if `P1_DATE_CHOOSER` is an APEX page variable, it should be prefixed with a colon.  Second, the alias `start_date` should appear after the `case` statement not as a part of each `then` clause.  You could double-quote the identifier if you want (though I wouldn't unless you're trying to create a case-sensitive identifier).  Single-quoting the identifier as you've done here turns it into a string literal which will also create a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select  START_DATE, 
        Round(Avg(Run_TIME), 3) as 'Average_RunTime', 
        Round(Max(Run_TIME), 3) as 'Max_RunTime', 
        Round(Median(Run_time), 3) as 'Median_RunTime' 
from 
    (Select job_id,
            (Case :P1_DATE_CHOOSER 
                 WHEN 'Daily' THEN TRUNC(start_time)
                 WHEN 'Weekly' THEN to_char(start_time, 'DAY')
                 WHEN 'Monthly' THEN to_char(start_time, 'MONTH') 
            END) AS 'START_DATE',  
            1440*(END_TIME - START_TIME)) as "RUN_TIME"
    from NI_INFA_ACTIVITY_LOG_V
    )
group by START_DATE 
order by START_DATE
;
```

First of all when ever you are binding the APEX variables or IDs, you have to 
prefix with `:` followed by item ID.

Second, in `case...when...then....end` the column alias name must be mentioned after `end` key word.

Third, dont use `group by` `order by` inside the subqueries. No use if you do.

Comment: Thank you!!! that worked except there was an additional parentheses, and the "...THEN TRUNC(start_time)" needed to be changed to match the other clauses datatype changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery needs an alias.  If you want to do this:

```
select something
from 
(subquery goes here)
```

You have to give it an alias

```
select something
from 
(subquery goes here) aliasName
```

There are other issues with your code as well.  The order by clause inside the subquery is useless at best.